# ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "django.middleware" does not define a "doc" class

Tags: python, django

A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

> [10/Mar/2014 02:38:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
>      Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 49, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\locale.py", line 24, in __init__
for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 346, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 341, in urlconf_module
self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\Asertova\Asertova\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
admin.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 29, in autodiscover
import_module('%s.admin' % app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cms\admin\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
import pageadmin
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cms\admin\pageadmin.py", line 30, in <module>
from cms.admin.change_list import CMSChangeList
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cms\admin\change_list.py", line 7, in <module>
from cms.utils.permissions import get_user_sites_queryset
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cms\utils\permissions.py", line 4, in <module>
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cms\plugin_pool.py", line 3, in <module>
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cms\plugin_base.py", line 85, in <module>
class CMSPluginBase(admin.ModelAdmin):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cms\plugin_base.py", line 30, in __new__
return super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 137, in __new__
attrs)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I don't represent how to solve so many problems arising at action on CMS manual.....

Answer (score 0):

You have `django.middleware.doc` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, but that does't exists on your system.

---

**Edited:**

You have typo in `settings.py`.

1. Replace `django.middleware.doc` with [`django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware).
2. Add your IP to [`INTERNAL_IPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-INTERNAL_IPS)

---

Description for [`django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware)

> Sends custom X-View HTTP headers to HEAD requests that come from IP addresses defined in the INTERNAL_IPS setting. This is used by Django’s automatic documentation system. Depends on AuthenticationMiddleware.

Comment: But it doesn't exist! Why do you want to install a class that doesn't exist? Why do you have it there in the first place?

Comment: I try to install django-cms on a manual and there this class is.

Comment: @user3388638: check again with a new answer.

Comment: Error C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\defaults.py:3: DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
  DeprecationWarning)

[10/Mar/2014 00:19:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 160247

Comment: @user3388638: this is DeprecationWarning. You have 500 error because `INTERNAL_IPS` is empty.

Comment: I don't understand how to add IP to INTERNAL_IPS.

Comment: @user3388638: try something like this INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)

Comment: error C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\defaults.py:3: DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
  DeprecationWarning)

[10/Mar/2014 02:09:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 160066

Comment: @user3388638: Did you replaced `127.0.0.1` with your IP?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't yield any result.

Comment: @user3388638: upgrade Django and then add your urls.py

Comment: TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Comment: Add that stack trace to the question.

Comment: @user3388638: Please check if [this](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/2415) issue can help you to resolve your problem